# why < is much faster than !=?

Tags: c, performance, operators, collatz

> Problem : Consider the following algorithm to generate a sequence of
>   numbers. Start with an integer n. If n is even, divide by 2. If n is
>   odd, multiply by 3 and add 1. Repeat this process with the new value
>   of n, terminating when n = 1. The input will consist of a series of
>   pairs of integers i and j, one pair of integers perline. All integers
>   will be less than 1,000,000 and greater than 0. 
>   For each pair of
>   input integers i and j, output i, j in the same order in which they
>   appeared in the input and then the maximum cycle length for integers
>   between and including i and j. These three numbers should be separated
>   by one space, with all three numbers on one line and with one line of
>   output for each line of input.

sample input :

```
1 10
```

sample output:

```
1 10 20
```

so i wrote this :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

struct line{int in1;int in2;int result;};

int cycle(int in);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int cycle(int in);
    char c;
    int firstIn=0;
    struct line l[500] ;
    int pointer=0;

    while(2<3){
        l[pointer].in1=0;
        l[pointer].in2=0;
        scanf("%u %u",&l[pointer].in1,&l[pointer].in2);
        if(l[pointer].in1<1||l[pointer].in2<1){
            break;
        }

        int maxCyc=0;
        int j,m;
        int min,max;
        if(l[pointer].in1>l[pointer].in2){
            max=l[pointer].in1;
            min=l[pointer].in2;
        }
        else{
            max=l[pointer].in2;
            min=l[pointer].in1;
        }
        for(j=min;j<=max;j++){

            m = cycle(j);
            if(m>maxCyc)
                maxCyc=m;
        }
        l[pointer].result=maxCyc;
        printf("%d %d %d\n",l[pointer].in1,l[pointer].in2,l[pointer].result);
        pointer++;
    }
}

int cycle(int in){
    int cyc = 1;
    while(in>1){
        if(in%2==0){
            cyc++;
            in=in/2;
        }
        else{
            cyc++;
            in=in*3+1;
        }
    }
    return cyc;
}
```

Its completly ok but when you change `while(in>1)` in cycle method to `while(in!=1)` it gets much more slower. my question is why?!

> Time when its `while(in>1)` : 0.683 sec
>
> and when its `while(in!=1)` : I waited more than 5 min nothing
>   happened yet :)
>
> for input : 1 1000000

there is no infinite loop or something because `in` cant get below 1 at all(for that it must be already 1) .

Best regards

Comment: Do you mean "**why != is much more faster than <**" in the title?

Comment: Why do you have `while(2<3)`? If you want an infinite loop just do e.g. `while(1)`. Though the compiler will optimize your expression to `1` anyway.

Comment: @AlterMann no in my case < is working faster ... thats why im confused

Comment: @JoachimPileborg just an old habit ;)

Comment: So change your title to: **why < is much more faster than !=?**

Comment: Do you mean `<` or `>`?

Comment: It is nowhere related to speed of `<` or `!=`. All depending on number of execution in loop.

Comment: Which compiler and which processor ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz its so much difference that i think its not related to compiler and proccessor but Compiler : Dev C++ 5.5.3 and Processor : intel core i5-3337U 1.8GHz

Comment: @Dayalrai What about the numbers? i only change that while. nothing else

Comment: "I waited more than 5 min nothing happened yet" - It is clear that you have a bug elsewhere in your code; it's not *slower*, it's in an infinite loop.  Most probably you are calling the function with an argument of 0.  You should use a debugger to fix this.

Comment: @amfad33: have a look at the generated assembly code.

Comment: `scanf("%u %u",&l[pointer].in1,&l[pointer].in2);` is using wrong format specifiers. Use `%d` for signed integers.

Comment: ... or use unsigned integers. The numbers involved are all required to be positive anyway.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth So Whats that infinite loop?!!! numbers are greater than 1 so they cant reach below 1 unless they get 1 first.

Comment: @dyp no difference ... still to slow

Comment: Check your assumption with a debugger.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth it works on smaller inputs. the problem starts since 13000 or so...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth no infinite loop detected by my debugger ...

Comment: If you think it is the operator that makes your code slow, create a smaller example to show this, where the number or operator executions is the same for the two operators you want to compare.

Comment: @scy7he its not the operators themselves... somehow != is changing my loop and make the mess ... I cant understand how

Comment: could there be any number where `in=in*3+1;` runs into an integer overflow and causes `in` to become negative? Then the operator would make a difference

Comment: @amfad33: With an input range of 1..1000000 your `int` variable `in` __will__ overflow and produce wrong (negative) values. Change it to `unsigned` or `long long`.

Comment: ok ... thats write ... thx

Comment: @IngoLeonhardt You should perhaps explain the overflow problem in an answer and show that the while loops are not equivalent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `cycle` with the input value `113383`, the process eventually sets `n` to 
827370449, and 3*827370449+1 is 2482111348, which is greater than the maximum `signed int` and is interpreted as -1812855948.  So there's your first negative number where there should be no negative number.

If this process then eventually sets `n` to -2, it will loop infinitely between -2 and -1 from then on. There may be other loops I haven't considered.

If you were to use an unsigned int, there is a possibility (I haven't checked) that this too will overflow eventually, which will not result in a negative value but will result in an *incorrect* value, invalidating your results.

No matter what integer representation you use, it would probably be a good idea to compare `n` with `(maximum-1)/3` at the top of each loop, where `maximum` is the largest possible positive value of your integer type, just to be sure you do not overflow.

Answer (score 1):

As you told me it was a simple overflow problem thx everyone.

max int value is `2,147,483,647;` So when i changed `int cycle(int in)` to `int cycle(long long int in)` my problem was solved.

i also figured it out that my first answer with `while(in>1)` was wrong.

When an integer overflow occurs,the value will go below 0 .That was the reason `while(in!=1)` was an infinte loop.

I was really tired that i didn't figure it out by myself. sorry for that :)